# unable to get the text property of the characters class, no change to line causing error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sub that will be passed a column letter, and for row 2 to the last row of that column, extract only the numbers from the cells and overwrite the cells with those numbers.`

```
Sub ExtractNumbersInColumn(ColWithNums As String)

Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, nStr As String, n As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("RefindData")

Dim rngStart As Range
Dim rngEnd As Range

Set rngStart = ws.Range(ColWithNums & "2")
Set rngEnd = ws.Range(ColWithNums & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
Set Rng = ws.Range(rngStart, rngEnd)

For Each Dn In Rng

For n = 1 To Len(Dn.Value)
    If Dn.Characters(n, 1).Text Like "[0-9]" Then
        nStr = nStr & Dn.Characters(n, 1).Text
    End If
Next n

Dn = Val(nStr): nStr = ""

Next Dn

End Sub`
```

I am getting an issue with this line:

```
 If Dn.Characters(n, 1).Text Like "[0-9]" Then
```

with the error - "unable to get the text property of the characters class"

After doing a little research this problem appears with older versions of Excel. I am using 2003. However, the simplified version of this code:

```
  Sub MG31May23
Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, nStr As String, n As Long
Set Rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Each Dn In Rng
For n = 1 To Len(Dn.Value)
    If Dn.Characters(n, 1).Text Like "[0-9]" Then
        nStr = nStr & Dn.Characters(n, 1).Text
    End If
Next n
Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(nStr): nStr = ""
Next Dn
End Sub
```

Works fine, and that particular line is not changed.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I have discovered that it does not like to look at a cell containing only numbers otherwise `.Text` will kick up a fuss. So the real question now is how can I alter this for it to be happy looking at cells that contain letters and numbers, as well as just numbers (but not do anything with obviously)

Comment: What does 'n' point to when it fails? All rows or somewhere further down? What is the 'format' of that cell versus prior?

Comment: I'm unclear on why `.Text` is there at all. `Dn.Characters(n, 1)` is all that is necessary. [Official docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198232.aspx) do not show .Text as a property of Range.Characters although I suppose it could be inherited as a subset Range object. .Text is the **displayed value** and can include extraneous characters and/or spaces from cell formatting; .Value does not.

Comment: @Jeeped - The `Range.Characters` property returns a [`Characters` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194098.aspx) which has a [`Text` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838596.aspx)

Comment: Right. So `=TODAY()` in a cell formatted as `dd-mmm-yyyy` produces `31-May-2017` for .Text, `05/31/2017` for .Value (depending a little on regional settings) and `42886` for .Value2. So why use `For n = 1 To Len(Dn.Value)` and then `Dn.Characters(n, 1).Text`?

Comment: Ok I have found the culprit, `.Text` doesn't like it when there is no text found,  and there are only numbers. So the solution to my question now is how can I alter it so that it is happy to look at column cells that contain text and numbers, as well as column cells with numbers (But not do anything with them obviously)

Comment: @Jeeped - you have to use the `.Text` property of the `Characters` object to access the text - it doesn't have a default property as far as I can see.  But it appears the `Characters` object of a cell containing a date does not have a `Text` property (which sort of makes sense).

Comment: Are you just trying to do `Mid(Dn.Value, n, 1)`?  Why use a `Characters` object at all?

Comment: `if IsNumeric(Mid(Dn.Value, n, 1)) then`

Comment: And FWIW, a cell containing a formula will also cause the `Characters` object to not have a `Text` property (which also makes sense).  Basically, the Characters.Text property seems to only be available on cells containing constant strings.

Comment: depends if you want numbers or only digits https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+vba+extract+numbers+from+text

Comment: If I have a column with cells that contain data like `TRFG1234` (Could be any combination of letters and numbers), all I really want in this cell for example is `1234` that is all

Answer (score 0):

With help from the commenters, this section of code works better to perform the task of number extraction:

```
   For n = 1 To Len(Dn.Value)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(Dn.Value, n, 1)) Then
        nStr = nStr & Mid(Dn.Value, n, 1)
    End If
Next n
```